# Disable a plugin for IE 11 only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, error-handling, hamburger-menu

There's a hamburger menu that the client wants to keep, however the site is very broken ... only in iE 11.

https://lavidaapartments.com

Is there any way to fix these errors I found in the console for IE 11?

SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
iwpmenu.js (30,21)

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'iwpmenu'
wp_iwpmenu.js (2,5)

Thank you in advance for any suggested solution.

Comment: I meant to change the subject to requests a 'fix' for the errors rather than disable it for IE.  ...I suppose this is an option however.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is generating an error on this File: iwpmenu.js, Line: 30, Column: 21, which maps to:

```
jQuery('#iwpmenu_bar').delay(delayval).removeClass('open').animate({
    [direction]: [direction_width_minus] -- Expected identifier, string or number
}, options.close_bar_delay, function() {
    jQuery(this).css('display', '').find("ul.menu").css("padding-left", "20px");
});
```

The error happens because IE11 does not support `computed property keys`, more information [here](https://ryanpcmcquen.org/javascript/2016/10/25/computed-property-names-are-awesome.html).

Comment: Is there any work around or fix?  If all  other browsers support this feature, is there anyway I can disable this for IE 11 only...and still use this plugin for modern browsers?

Comment: You need to eliminate that syntax from the plugin. The good news is that the plugin is easily edited, the bad news is that you will need to find someone with write access to your site to do it.

Comment: Another thing you can do is contact the author of the plugin, and ask for his help.

Comment: thanks - I have asked the developer, and he's been working on it a while - I guess he doesn't think it's easy ;(

Comment: Well, I don't know what other errors exist on your site. The error I mentioned is fixed easily, since anyone can edit the plugin. But you mentioned that there was a second error. That error could be automatically fixed when this error is fixed, or then again it could be something more complicated. It's better to let your developer handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bastos.sergio, the answer is to eliminate the syntax from the plugin.

Since I'm not a programmer, I hope to find someone that can make it happen for us.

Thank you!